# Gizmodo RSS Feed getting stale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rss, feed, feedjira

I started pulling information from blogs into an app I am building using RSS. I have a cron job that runs every minute and does a fetch and parse of the rss feeds of multiple sites. New blog posts are added to my database everytime a new article shows up in the feed. I am using [Feedjira](http://feedjira.com) to do the retrieving and parsing of the feed. Everything works perfect for every blog I have tried so far except Gizmodo. After about 10 mins the RSS feed I receive stops updating, even though the blog keeps updating. I am not sure what is wrong and how to go about investigating it. DO big sites like Gizmodo have a rate at which u can check their RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do! Which is why you have to consider [implementing thins like PubSubHubbub](http://blog.superfeedr.com/howto-pubsubhubbub/) which will let you be notified when some feeds are updated.